# Android Studio unable to access project files

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having an issue with Android Studio. The IDE is unable to access my project files, it only displays loading.. I don't know what caused it. It occured after that Android Studio prompted me to install some plus-ins which I did. The problem occured after that. I don't know if someone faced this issue before.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try File > Invalidate Cache and Restart option

Comment: Unfortunately Invalidate cache and restart is not a solution for everything,I tried it, but the problem still persist

Comment: @Shid true, but it’s sometimes the right solution you wish you tried before sinking hours into the wrong solutions.

Comment: @flopshot You're right, it was actually the first thing I tried, when it didn't work I got anxious for some reasons since it usually solves a big amount of issues. Turns out it was plugin that was messing things around.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there was an issue in the installation of the plugin (MakeFile), disabling it aand restarting made Android Studio work normally again